# PWA add to home screen - wrong icon size / cut

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I'm building a PWA and I can't figure out how Chrome is choosing the home screen ICON (Android + Windows 10). PS: using Edge chromium works as expected.
On my website, the Icons look good (there's enough space between the top of the icon and the "j" itself, even if the checkbox "Show only the minimum safe area for maskable icons" is checked)
[image]
When I'm prompted to add the app to home screen, the logo still looks OK.
[image]
BUT after the installation, the logo seems to have been cut (not enough space between the top of the black circle and the "j").
[image]
PS: sorry for the background, I used paint to edit my black background, so you can see the logo.

Comment: I'm encountering the exact same issue. Did you find out the reason behind this by any chance?

Comment: @AradAlvand I don't remember encountering it anymore. Not sure if that's because I'm using this repository to create my favicons or not https://github.com/johnykes/PWA-favicon-generator. You can try it.

Comment: I see. Thank you.